# Synchronising layout constraint animation with device rotation

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm struggling with textfield bottom constrain animation when the keyboard is up and the device is rotating. Basically I need to synchronize the textfield position change animation with the rotation animation. Just like in the video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbMYVEdodJQ

I'm using viewWillTransition(to size:)-method to get animation duration and curve parameters used for device rotation animation. That' ok.

Then I'm using Notification center notification called UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame to inform me the keyboard size so I can move the textField accordingly. Thats ok too. Unfortunately the UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame-notification happens always after the viewWillTransition(to size:)-method is called.

Any advice how I should synchronize my animation? Below is the code where the animation is out of sync.

```
    func setKeyboardObservers() {

     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame , object: nil)
}



override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in

        self.deviceRotating = true

        self.animationDuration = context.transitionDuration
        self.animationCurve = UInt(context.completionCurve.rawValue)

    }) { (_) in

      self.deviceRotating = false
    }

}



@objc func keyboardWillChange(_ notification: NSNotification) {

    let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue


    if deviceRotating {

         textFieldBottomContstrain.constant = -keyboardFrame.height

        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: animationDuration, delay: 0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurve), animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: You don’t need to synchronize anything. You don’t need to animate anything. A change in constraints made in `animateAlongside` or in the keyboard notification is automatically animated.

Comment: Sorry, does not work. I get correct automatic animation only if I call animateAlong inside the viewWillTransition-method. But I can’t do that because at that point I don’t know the upcoming keyboard size. All I can do, is save the  coordinator in the variable and wait until the keyboard notification comes and then call coordinator.animateAlong. But at that point, for some reason, nothing inside the animateAlong-block is executed.

Comment: And yes I have noticed that change in the constraints is automatically animated after a keyboard notification, and that’s causing me the problems. Because at that point the automatic animation is synced with keyboard. I need it to be synced with device rotation instead. I have also tried to find a way to disable  that automatic animation after a keyboard notification so I can use my custom animation for constrains, but without luck. Any idea how this can be achieved?